# How to evaluate ML image classifier with confidence

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, classification

Suppose I have a model that classifies images in to one of n categories. I know how to calculate the accuracy and sensitivity based just on the output label. However, I want to be more specific. How could I also incorporate the confidence percentage which is produced with each output???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating) to obtain a confidence interval of your model on the dataset. A full demonstration [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/calculate-bootstrap-confidence-intervals-machine-learning-results-python/). If you want it for an individual sample, you may define another list, like the `stat` list, and store the predicted probabilities for that individual in there instead.